# Problem Installing QGIS to Samsung Galaxy Tab3

Tags: qgis, installation, android

I try to install stable and nightly(18/09/2014 last nightly) versions of QGIS to Samsung Galaxy Tab3 (Android) but unfortunately I can't. When the installation is completed asked me to confirm the installation of the necessary libraries (Ministro). I tried to open the program showed the following error "The application Ministro cannot satisfy the requirements of the application".
Any help or ideas for what is the problem or what I can do.
It is the same problem like this bug report http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6497

Comment: Should work with Ministro II https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.necessitas.ministro&hl=en

Comment: I did not mention, but when the installation of Qgis finish the libraries are installed normally but nothing. I put the file configure Ministro and switched to unstable version but again nothing.